# Error when connecting to powerbi dataset using adomd

Tags: c#, powerbi, xmla, adomd.net

I am completely new to xmla and attempting to use the 19.22.0.1 version of `Microsoft.AnalysisServices.SdomdClient.NetCore.retail.amd64` to connect to a dataset in a Powerbi premium workspace.  I lifted the connection string from the excel file generated by the `analyze in excel` option but attempting to use it results in a the following `AdomdConnectionException`.  Updating the connection string based upon the documentation [guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/instances/connection-string-properties-analysis-services?view=asallproducts-allversions) results in the same beahvior.   The excel spreadsheet works fine which I believe means the xmla endpoints settings are set appropriately.  I am able to access the dataset and linked reports via app.powerbi.com which suggest that I have the necessary permissions.

```
var tenantId = "<AAD Tenant Guid>";
var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions
{
    VisualStudioTenantId = tenantId,
    VisualStudioCodeTenantId = tenantId,
    SharedTokenCacheTenantId = tenantId,
    InteractiveBrowserTenantId = tenantId,
});
var token = await credential.GetTokenAsync(new TokenRequestContext(scopes: new[] { "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api" }));
// https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/instances/connection-string-properties-analysis-services?view=asallproducts-allversions
var connectionString = @$"Provider=MSOLAP.8;Integrated Security=ClaimsToken;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=<DataSet Name>;Data Source=powerbi://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/<workspace>;MDX Compatibility=1;Safety Options=2;MDX Missing Member Mode=Error;Password={token.Token}";
```

**Exception 1 - bad schema in the URL**

> Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnectionException: The
> remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.  --->
> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401)
> Unauthorized.    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()    at
> Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.ASAzureUtility.PutHttpJsonData[TRequest,TResult](Uri
> uri, Dictionary`2 headers, TRequest requestObject, Int32 timeoutMs)
> at
> Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.ASAzureUtility.ResolvePowerBICluster(Uri
> discoverUrl, String token, TimeLeft timeLeft, AsInstanceType
> asInstanceType)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
> Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.ASAzureUtility.ThrowConnectionException(WebException
> ex, AsInstanceType asInstanceType)    at
> Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.ASAzureUtility.ResolvePowerBICluster(Uri
> discoverUrl, String token, TimeLeft timeLeft, AsInstanceType
> asInstanceType)    at
> Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.ConnectionInfo.ValidateAndSetPbiDatasourceAndLocation()
> at
> Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.ConnectionInfo.HandleAsAzureconnections()
> at
> Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.ConnectionInfo.ValidateAndCompleteConnectionConfiguration()
> at
> Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.ConnectionInfo.SetConnectionString(String
> cs)    at
> Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.ConnectionInfo..ctor(String
> connectionString)    at
> Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnection.XmlaClientProvider.Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnection.IXmlaClientProviderEx.set_ConnectionString(String
> value)    at
> Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnection.set_ConnectionString(String
> value)    at
> Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnection..ctor(String
> connectionString)

**Update #1**
A couple of tweaks to get further.

1. the connection string I got from excel used the schema `azurebi` instead of `powerbi`
2. shifted the token scope to `https://analysis.windows.net/powebi/api`

This allows the `AdomdConnection` to be instantiated but now when attempting to `Open()` the connection it throws exception #2 below.

**Exception 2**

> Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnectionException: The
> remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
>
> Technical Details: RootActivityId:
> 025c6866-1776-48e0-a43f-677cdde76a20 Date (UTC): 7/8/2021 11:36:14 PM
> ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
> at
> Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.HttpRequestResponseExtensions.GetResponseWithErrorHandling(HttpWebRequest
> httpWebRequest, Boolean isPbiPremium)    at
> Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.HttpStream.WaitForAndUpdateHttpResponseContainingXmlaPayload()
> at
> Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.HttpStream.GetResponseStream()
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.ASAzureUtility.ThrowConnectionException(WebException
> ex, AsInstanceType asInstanceType)    at
> Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.HttpStream.GetResponseStream()
> at
> Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.HttpStream.GetResponseDataType()
> at
> Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.CompressedStream.GetResponseDataType()
> at
> Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.XmlaClient.EndRequest(Boolean
> useBinaryXml)    at
> Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.XmlaClient.EndRequest()    at
> Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.XmlaClient.CreateSession(ListDictionary
> properties, Boolean sendNamespaceCompatibility, String sessionToken)
> at
> Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.XmlaClient.CreateSession(ListDictionary
> properties, Boolean sendNamespaceCompatibility)    at
> Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnection.XmlaClientProvider.Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnection.IXmlaClientProviderEx.CreateSession(Boolean
> sendNamespaceCompatibility)    at
> Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnection.ConnectToXMLA(Boolean
> createSession, Boolean isHTTP)    at
> Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnection.Open()

Comment: Did you get this working in the end? I am facing the same problem